# Updating view bounds after canvas transformations (rotate, scale, transform)

Tags: java, android-canvas, android

I am trying to figure out how to update the bound of my view to match the canvas after I applied changes to rotate, scale and transform.

This is my class for a custom textview. I have rotate working like I want but the view is not wrapping around my canvas.

```
public class RDTextView extends TextView {

public int angle = 0;

public RDTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{ // Save the current matrix
    canvas.save();
    // Rotate this View at its center
    canvas.rotate(angle,this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);
    // Draw it --- will add scale
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // Restore to the previous matrix
    canvas.restore();
}
```

My issue is that I have a border around the view but after I change the angle it doesn't follow the canvas shape.

[image: Before rotation]
[image: After rotation]

The border is unchanged after rotation but I would like to update it to match the content.

Answer (score 0):

I just made following code for my needs.

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;

    import javax.swing.JLabel;


    public class RotatedLabel extends JLabel {

        //we need to remember original size
        private int originalWidth = 0;
        private int originalHeight = 0;

        //I do rotation around the center of label, so save it too
        private int originX = 0;
        private int originY = 0;

        public RotatedLabel(String text, int horizotalAlignment) {
            super(text, horizotalAlignment);
        }

        @Override
        public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            //save new data
            originX = x + width / 2;
            originY = y + height / 2;
            originalWidth = width;
            originalHeight = height;
            super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        };

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            int w2 = getWidth() / 2;
            int h2 = getHeight() / 2;

            double angle = -Math.PI / 2;//it's our angle

            //now we need to recalculate bounds
            int newWidth = (int)Math.abs(originalWidth * Math.cos(angle) + originalHeight * Math.sin(angle));
            int newHeight = (int)Math.abs(originalWidth * Math.sin(angle) + originalHeight * Math.cos(angle));

            g2d.rotate(angle, w2, h2);
            super.paint(g);

            //set new bounds
            super.setBounds(originX - newWidth / 2, originY - newHeight / 2, newWidth, newHeight);
        }
    }
```